# css animation scale not working in chrome

Tags: css

/* html */
this is html section.

```
 <div class="second-menu-2-container">
        <div class="second-menu-2">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">world</a>
            <a href="#">Tech</a>

        </div>    
    </div>
```

/* css 3 */
this is css 3 section.  I put `<a>` tag some hover scale  transform, but not working .

```
 .second-menu-2-container {
            background-color: #A91717;
            width: 100%;
        }


 .second-menu-2 {
            width: 1000;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 30px;

        }
 .second-menu-2 a {
            transition: all 2s ease-in-out;  
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: relative;
            top: 8px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border-right: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
            font-weight: 100;   

        }

  .second-menu-2 a:hover {
            transform: scale(2);

        }
```

This is the jsfiddle address :https://jsfiddle.net/libaoming/xg692wy3/

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` for the links, https://jsfiddle.net/xg692wy3/1/ (It's not a nice effect though, so you might want to adapt parameters such as value of the the scale transformation, origin, add border on both sides of the links or keep it out of them in the first place, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` on transformed element to make it work. See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/matikucharski/xg692wy3/3/